# Plot output of second return variable with fplot

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a multi-variate function myfun

```
function [y1,...,yN] = myfun(x1,...,xM)
```

which I would like to plot using fplot, keeping all but one variables fixed, for example like this:

```
fplot('myfun(0,0,0,x,0,0,0,...,0)',[0,10]);
```

This creates a plot of y1 by default. How can I get fplot to show the graph of y2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `fplot` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html):

> If the function returns more than one value for a given *x*, then *y* is a matrix whose columns contain each component of *f(x)*.

`fplot` will only display the first output of the given function. If you put the outputs in matrix form (a column for each output value) then `fplot` will display all of them as in the second example in the documentation. If you want to use it for a certain output only, you will have to create a duplicate or a wrapper function with only that output.